# Проблема со скроллом

Tags: css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я делаю галерею, мне необходимо сделать блок, который выходит за края экрана.
он состоит из дивов внутри которых вложен img. мне необходимо что бы полоса прокрутки была внутри этого блока, но она появляется вместо конкретного длинного блока, у всего body у блока тоже появляется скролл, но на всю длину и его нельзя подвигать - нет места. если я не оборачиваю img в див, то все работает так как мне надо. оборачиваю из за потребности в ::before.

как мне сделать скролл только у длинного блока?

https://codepen.io/aqualaqe/pen/bGwgvmq

`````
        background-color: #000000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }

    .s2{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        flex-basis: 500px;
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 15000px;
    }
    .s3{        
        width: 300px;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: aqua;
        margin: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .s1{
        
    }````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оно?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-grid__inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.gallery-grid__inner > * {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.gallery-card {
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background-color: purple;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.gallery-card:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-grid">
  <div class="gallery-grid__inner">
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
    <div class="gallery-card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо! оно самое. а то я уже завернулся в теплый плед, включил грустную музыку и сел перед окном, опустошенно глядя как одинокие снежинки, надменно танцуют на ветру насмехаясь над моей беспомощность.

Comment: @ЭмильГрицай, после Вашего текста я чуть сам депрессию не поймал :D